# tar_map over tibble list-column drops class

Tags: r, targets-r-package

Consider this reprex:

```r
targets::tar_dir({ # tar_dir() runs code from a temporary directory.
targets::tar_script({

  library(dplyr)

  values_df = tibble(index = 1:3, df = list(mtcars))

  list(
    tarchetypes::tar_map(
      values_df, names = "index",
      targets::tar_target(x, slice(df, index))
    )
  )
})
targets::tar_manifest()
})
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name  command
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 x_1   "slice(list(c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, \n     24.4, 22.8, …
#> 2 x_2   "slice(list(c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, \n     24.4, 22.8, …
#> 3 x_3   "slice(list(c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, \n     24.4, 22.8, …
```

As you can see, `values_df` is a tibble with a numeric column "index" and a list column of data frames "df". However `tar_map` seems to drop the data frame class of the "df" elements, which will cause an error (because `dplyr::slice()` does not operate on lists). Am I doing something wrong? How do I prevent `tar_map()` from dropping the class of the elements of the "df" list column?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/ropensci/tarchetypes/discussions/105 and try `df = quote(list(mtcars))` instead of `df = list(mtcars)`.

Comment: @landau fair enough, that works for my trivial example. In reality my pipeline creates `values_df` from a function (reading a config file). I can make the creation of `values_df` a target and then use dynamic branching, but I was hoping to use static branching so that the resulting target names would be meaningful.

Comment: This time you should use metaprogramming! This might be hard, but give [Hadley's book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html) a try.